# Assign boolean value to array of enum types C#

Tags: c#, enums, boolean

From this enum type:

```
public enum MySqlObjectType
{
    Table = 1,
    Procedure = 2,
    View = 4,
    Function = 8,
    Trigger = 512,
    User = 128,
    Event = 256
}
```

I want to make something like this:

```
Options.Load[MySqlObjectType.Event] = true;
Options.Load[MySqlObjectType.Function] = false;
```

How field in Options class should look like so I can do something as above? And is it possible?

Comment: Sounds like a bitmask (`Flags` enum), a simple `MySqlObjectType
` field can handle all these operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a dictionary to store the enum -> boolean key/value pair:

```
public class Options
{
    public Options()
    {
        Load = new Dictionary<MySqlObjectType, bool>();
    }

    public Dictionary<MySqlObjectType, bool> Load { get; set; }
}
```

---

As Ivan said, you probably just want a simple flags enum:

```
public enum MySqlObjectType
{
    Table = 1,
    Procedure = 2,
    View = 4,
    Function = 8,
    Trigger = 512,
    User = 128,
    Event = 256
}
```

Note that all values should be powers of 2 and unique.

```
MySqlObjectType value = MySqlObjectType.Event | MySqlObjectType.User;
```

To check if a value is set, you can do:

```
if ((value & MySqlobjectType.Event) == MySqlObjectType.Event) {
```

I think you can also do this as of .NET Framework v4:

```
if (value.HasFlag(MySqlObjectType.Event)) {
```

Comment: Can't quite remember off top of my head, but wouldn't you need to either preload the list with all keys, or at least check the key exists before assigning a value?

Comment: No. With dictionaries you can just do Load[key] = value; and it will create/assign it. It is advisable to use TryGetValue(...) to read a dictionary, however.

Comment: @john Thanks it was helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

An other way to create single flags enum is:

```css
public enum MySqlObjectType
{
    Table = 1 << 0,
    Procedure = 1 << 1,
    View = 1 << 2,
    Function = 1 << 3,
    Trigger = 1 << 9,
    User = 1 << 7,
    Event = 1 << 8
}
```